# Access path of a file in java array

Tags: java, directory, path

I am using an array of files.

```
String[] allFiles = new String[]{"real.xml", "fake.xml"};
```

I am getting this error that

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\rio\rio-workspace\real.xml
```

I am trying to run command to know where it is looking for the file. I came across this solution but it doesn't work with array.

```
System.out.println(allFiles.toAbsolutePath());
```

Would appreciate if someone give right command to know about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the sample code you did and also add more clarity in your question

Comment: All relative files are filled in from the value in `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] allFiles = { "output.txt", "test.txt" };

        // First method
        for (String file : allFiles) {
            System.out.println(Paths.get(file).toAbsolutePath());
        }

        // Second method (by using Stream)
        Arrays.stream(allFiles).forEach(file -> System.out.println(Paths.get(file).toAbsolutePath()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All relative files are filled in from the value in `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
File[] thoseFiles = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < thoseFiles.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(thoseFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Or if you chose to have the files in a folder

```
File[] thoseFiles = new File("ThatFolder").listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < thoseFiles.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(thoseFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This can be expanded with a [Filefilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html)